# Windows 7 detected, but no option to install alongside windows

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

**Situtation**

1. I want to install ubuntu alongside windows 7.
2. I have 3 partitions on my internal hard-disk (C,D,E) and one external hard disk drive.
3. I have removed external hard disk drive (from USB port) as i do not want to mess-up with my data on the this drive.
4. I formated (as NTFS) my drive D in windows 7 to install ubuntu on this drive.
5. Created a bootable USB with ubuntu 14.04.1

**Problem**

1. Installation is showing Windows 7 detected but no option to install alongside windows.

[image: Screen-shot]

**Updated**

> > output of     sudo parted -l
> >
> > http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8257304/

Comment: Are you sure you have only three partitions and not 4 (one hidden)? Please post the output of `sudo parted -l` from the terminal. Edit the question to include the output.

Comment: added output of sudo parted -l @muru

Comment: That is a very tricky situation. Normally, Ubuntu would try to use the extended/logical partition, but it's only 10GB and right between two other partitions. I assume this D drive you're talking of is the 10GB one?

Comment: yes that drive is 10 GB one. @muru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I formated my drive D in windows 7 to install ubuntu on this drive.

To clarify, is that partition currently unallocated space? Usually you need to shrink your windows partition before installing to provide enough free space for the new install. You might need to defragment your hard drive before doing so because linux will need a contiguous block of memory. If all of your files are scattered over the partition it might be impossible to shrink the windows partition enough for the install.

Edit:
If you have already moved all data from that partition, then delete the partition to create unallocated space. This will be where ubuntu is installed. Ubuntu can't automatically guess that your NTFS partition is where you want it to install, all Ubuntu can use is the unallocated space on the drive.

Comment: it's not unallocated space, i formatted that drive as NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the simplest thing that can be done is *delete* the D: partition (not format it). Either using GParted or the Windows Disk Management tool. This will create unused space, which the installer can go ahead and use.